# To Inherit a bootsrap class to all my tables from css, not html

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can I inherit a bootstrap class to all my tables without editing my html file?. All the tables are generated with PHP, and I want to give them some format. I was searching, but the only thing that I could do is to use pure CSS or jquery only. I've tried to modify the php file but it doesn't work (sends me a PHP error).

Thank you

The PHP code isn't mine, I'm in a project and I'm doing the view parts, anyway, that is the piece of code that sends the table:

```
function arrayToTable($array, $recursive = false, $return = false, $null = '&nbsp;'){
    // Sanity check
    if(empty($array) || !is_array($array)){ return false; }
    if(!isset($array[0]) || !is_array($array[0])){ $array = array($array); }

    // Start the table
    $table = "<table>\n";
    // The header
    $table .= "\t<tr>";
    // Take the keys from the first row as the headings
    foreach (array_keys($array[0]) as $heading) {
        $table .= '<th>' . $heading . '</th>';
    }
    $table .= "</tr>\n";
// The body
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        $table .= "\t<tr>" ;
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            $table .= '<td>';

            // Cast objects
            if (is_object($cell)) { $cell = (array) $cell; }
            if ($recursive === true && is_array($cell) && !empty($cell)) {
                // Recursive mode
                $table .= "\n" . array2table($cell, true, true) . "\n";
            } else {
                $table .= (strlen($cell) > 0) ?
                    $cell :
                    $null;
            }
            $table .= '</td>';
        }
        $table .= "</tr>\n";
    }
    // End the table
    $table .= '</table>';
    // Method of output
    if ($return === false) {
        echo $table;
    } else {
        return $table;
    }
}
```

If I change the table variable, it sends me an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'table' (T_STRING) in /path/file.php on line 16

EDIT:
I had to do a bootstrap on "my way" because it affected the project view that I've had in the whole version, but anyway, the answer of Marty looks very interesting and is a good tool to consider. Thanks !

Comment: You'll need to post some code if you want to get help with your issue.

Comment: From looking into how twitter-bootstrap applies the table styles to elements which is by targeting a selector `.table` and similar, you could perhaps easily add that into the class attribute in the PHP code. If you post the PHP code that generates the tables it should be more obvious how that can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user3250573, when you say "inherit", do you mean that you want to apply [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) formatting to your tables? I think Bootstrap just asks that you add the "table" class to your tables to make them Bootstrap-enabled.

If you can use jQuery, then you can probably iterate through all the tables in the output and add the "table" class to any tables that don't already have the class. Here's sample JavaScript using jQuery that demonstrates this idea: http://jsfiddle.net/eb5th/

```
$("table:not([class~='table'])").addClass("table");
```